# XSLT problem with output when meet an IF condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I can't handle with the following issue. I want to use an XSLT to transform an import xml in the needed format for the extension I am using. I want to set a specific value for a parameter when it met a specific IF condition.

This is the input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item><InStock>In Stock</InStock></item>
<item><InStock>Out of Stock</InStock></item>
</items>
```

This is what I am trying to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="product">
        <xsl:element name="Items">
            <xsl:for-each select="item">
                <xsl:element name="Item">
                        <xsl:element name="quantity_and_stock_status">
                        <xsl:if test="InStock = 'In Stock'">
                        1
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="InStock = 'Out of Stock'">
                        0
                        </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You have a template matching `product`, but there is no such element in your XML. Did you mean to match `items` here?

Comment: The type of the template is choosing on the previous step in the extension, then it comes the XSLT transformation based on the previous choice.

Comment: You may need to explain more about this extension. At the moment, all that can be  said that the XSLT will not apply to your XML, as the XSLT is looking to match `product` which is not in your XML. It might help if you also said what output you are currently getting, and what you expect. Thank you!

Comment: You haven't asked a question. You've said what you're doing (good!) but you haven't said what output you want to produce and how your current code fails.

Comment: XML is case sensitive, you are using "Item" and "item" as if they were interchangeable.